# $\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$ is homeomorphic to some subspace of $\Pi_{j\in J}X'_j$ if $I\subseteq J$ and if $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}\subseteq\{X'_j\}_{j\in J}$

Tags: general-topology

Let be $I$ and $J$ two collection of indexes such that $I\subseteq J$ and let be $\mathfrak{X}_I=\{(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i):i\in I\}$ and $\mathfrak{X}'_J=\{(X'_j,\mathcal{T'}_j):j\in J\}$ two collection of topological spaces such that $\mathfrak{X}_I\subseteq\mathfrak{X'}_J$, or rather we suppose that there exist an injiective function $\varphi:I\rightarrow J$ such that $X_i=X_{\varphi(i)}$. Previously we say that we use the notations ${}_{{}_{I}}\pi_i$ and ${}_{{}_J}\pi_j$ to indicate the projections on $\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$ and $\Pi_{j\in J}X'_j$.

Well we want prove that $\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$ is homeomorphic to some subspace of $\Pi_{j\in J}X'_j$.

So we pick a $z\in\Pi_{j\in J}X'_j$ and we define a function $\phi$ from $\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$ to $\Pi_{j\in J}X'_j$ by the condition

1. $$
   [\phi(g)](j):=\begin{cases}g(j),\quad if\quad j\in I\\z(j),\quad otherwise\end{cases}
   $$

and we prove that it is an embedding in $\Pi_{j\in J}X'_j$. So for starters we prove that $\phi$ is injective: if it is $\phi(g_1)=\phi(g_2)$ so it is $[\phi(g_1)](j)=[\phi(g_2)](j)$ for each $j\in J$ and  in particular for any $j\in I$ by the condition $1$ it result that $g_1(j)=g_2(j)$, that is $g_1=g_2$ and thus $\phi$ is injective; so the function $\Phi$ from $\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$ to the subspace $\phi(\Pi_{i\in I}X_i)$ defined by the condiction

2. $$\Phi(g):=\phi(g)
   $$

is a bijection. Now we have to prove that $\Phi$ is is an homeomorphism. Previously we observe that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function then the function $F$ from $X$ to $f(X)$ defined as $F(X)=f(x)$ is continuous, since for any open set $U$ in $Y$ it result that $f^{-1}(f(X)\cap U)=f^{-1}(f(X))\cap f^{-1}(U)=X\cap f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U)$. So we observe that

$$
{}_{{}_J}\pi_j\circ\phi=\begin{cases}{}_{{}_J}\pi_j,\quad if\quad j\in I\\z_j,\quad otherwise\end{cases}
$$

is a continuous function for each $j\in J$ (indeed the projection ${}_{{}_J}\pi_j$ are continuous and the costant functions $z_j$ are continuous) and so by the universal mapping theorem for products we can claim that $\phi$ is continuous and so for what we observed $\Phi$ is continuous. Then $\Phi^{-1}$ from the subspace $\phi(\Pi_{i\in I}X_i)$ to $\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$ is defined by the condiction

3. $$
   [\Phi^{-1}(f)](i)=f(j),\quad for\quad each\quad j\in I
   $$

and so we observe that ${}_{{}_I}\pi_i\circ\Phi^{-1}={}_{{}_J}\pi_i|_{\phi(\Pi_{i\in I}X_i)}$ is continuous for each $i\in I\subseteq J$ (indeed the restriction to the subspace $\phi(\Pi_{i\in I}X_i)$ of continuous function ${}_{{}_J}\pi_i$ is continuous) and by the universal mapping theorem for products we can claim that $\Phi^{-1}$ is continuous and so $\Phi$ is an homeomorphism and so $\phi$ is an embedding of $\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$ in $\Pi_{j\in J}X'_j$.

Is it the proof correct? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Your notation is confusing. I suggest you write $\mathfrak{X}'_J=\{(X'_j,\mathcal{T}'_j):j\in J\}$ instead of $\mathfrak{X}_J=\{(X_j,\mathcal{T}_j):j\in J\}$.

Comment: Okay, now I edit the question. Anyway what can you do about my proof?

Comment: By the way, you must add the requirement that the $X'_j$ are nonempty for $j \notin I$. If one $X_i$ is empty, then the theorem is trivial. If all $X_i$ are nonempty, then also **all** $X'_j$  are nonempty and you find $z$ in their product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but I have a suggestion to make it more transparent by using only the universal property of the product.  We shall write $\pi_i :  \prod_{i \in I} X_i  \to X_i$ and $\pi'_j :  \prod_{j \in J} X'_j  \to X'_j$ for the projections and $\iota_i : X_i \to X'_i$ for the inclusion maps.

Let us first redefine $\phi$ a little more abstractly:

The maps $\phi_i = \iota_i \circ \pi_i $ for $i \in I$ and the constant maps $\phi_j : \prod_{i \in I} X_i \to X'_j, \phi_j(f) = z(j)$, for $j \in J \setminus I$ determine a unique continuous $\phi : \prod_{i \in I} X_i \to \prod_{j\in J} X'_j$ such that $\pi'_j \circ \phi = \phi_j$.

The map $\phi$ restricts to a unique continuous surjection $\Phi: \prod_{i \in I} X_i \to P = \phi(\prod_{i \in I} X_i)$. This means $\iota  \circ \Phi = \phi$, where $\iota : P \to \prod_{j \in J} X'_j$ denotes the inclusion map.

For $i \in I$, the projection $\pi'_i : \prod_{j \in j} X'_j \to X'_i$ has the property $\pi'_i \circ \phi = \phi_i =  \iota_i \circ \pi_i$, thus restricts to a unique continuous $\pi''_i : P \to X_i$ satisfying $\iota_i \circ \pi''_i = \pi'_i \circ \iota$.

The $\pi''_i$ determine a unique continuous $\pi'' :  P \to \prod_{i \in I} X_i$ such that $\pi_i \circ \pi'' = \pi''_i$.

1. $\pi'' \circ \Phi = id$: We have $\iota_i \circ \pi_i \circ \pi'' \circ \Phi = \iota_i \circ \pi''_i \circ \Phi = \pi'_i \circ \iota \circ \Phi = \pi'_i \circ \phi = \phi_i = \iota_i \circ \pi_i$. Since $\iota_i$ is injective, we conclude $\pi_i \circ \pi'' \circ \Phi = \pi_i = \pi_i \circ id$ for all $i  \in I$, thus $\pi'' \circ \Phi = id$.
2. $\Phi \circ \pi'' = id'$: By 1. we have $\Phi \circ \pi'' \circ \Phi = \Phi \circ id = id' \circ \Phi$. Since $\Phi$ is surjective, we conclude $\Phi \circ \pi'' = id'$.

But 1. and 2. imply that $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Sorry, I don't undesteand well the definition of $\rho_i$; could you explain better, please?

Comment: Then you wrote $\pi'_i : \prod_{j \in j} X'_i \to X'_i$: perhaps did you want write $\pi'_i : \prod_{j \in j} X'_j\to X'_i$? or rather you wanted use the index $j$ in the factors of the product and not the index $i$, right?

Comment: Second comment: Thank you, it was a typo. I corrected it and also replaced $\rho_i$ by $\pi''_i$ to make notation closer to the projection $\pi'_i$. First comment: We have $\pi'_i \circ \phi = \iota_i \circ \pi_i$, thus $\pi'_i(P) = \pi'_i(\phi(\prod_{i \in I} X_i) = \iota_i(\pi_i(\prod_{i \in I} X_i) \subset X_i$ which gives the desired restriction $\pi''_i :  P \to X_i$ of $\pi'_i$.